# Laravel Blade: not showing changes

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

laravel 5.3

Changes on my blade templates only show when in responsive mode. I've cleared the cache, views, and sessions in /storage with the artisan commands and manually. Tried different browsers (+incognito), updated virtualbox and deleted the virtual machine. I'm using homestead to develop locally.

I can see the changes on the cache files in /storage being reflected correctly and when I look at the source in the browser the changes are there, but they just don't show up visually. When I go into responsive mode they appear! When I get out of responsive mode they disappear and go back to displaying what the old code was displaying, the source code is unchanged it still shows the updated code in responsive and normal mode.

Any ideas whats happening? maybe extra caching by homestead somewhere? or is this the browser? I've used different browsers and cleared their cache though which is really confusing.

Comment: Perhaps this is your html / css playing up, not laravel/blade/homestead?

Comment: Yes the cached views being correctly updated leads me to believe this might not have to do with Laravel, but then what are my next steps? But then the page showing old deleted headers and styles would tell me that its still a cache issue, so ive cleared the browser cache and that doesn't do anything so not sure what my next step to debug this issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the data I was changing was in two places so I just simply had to update it in both places.